# Python reading in rows of xlsx by column name?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'd like to think I'm *almost* a solid novice at Python by now and I'm trying to start an ambitious new project to automate a ton of work that all starts with reading in a very complicated excel workbook (openpyxl). I've got two things I can't quite figure out.

#### Question 1

This excel workbook has had years of changes made, and not everyone is using the latest version (a problem for a different day). For that reason, if I could read values in by Column Name instead of number, it would be great. If the current value for "Hostname" was in column 8, and later they move it to Column 10, my script breaks.

```
for row in assets_tab.iter_rows(min_row=19, min_col = 3,max_col=50): 
    hostName=row[7].value
```

The column names generally stay the same, so if I can define a header row and use that to label the columns, it would be helpful.

#### Question 2

I'm struggling to figure out the best way to store this data in Python. For now, it's just a simple for loop that defines normal str variables, but I'd really like to load up some sort of array. I was looking at the 'Dict: Simple Data Objects' in [this article](https://realpython.com/python-data-structures/#dict-simple-data-objects), and it seems like the best way, but I can't figure out how to make "Car1", "Car2" etc work.

Example Code:

```
car1 = {
   "color": "red",
   "mileage": 3812.4,
   "automatic": True,
}
```

So, if I wanted to copy that, I could use "device1", "device2" etc (no idea how many devices I'll have, so it has to be dynamic). So I thought I'd try to implement some sort of counter in my code, but it didn't work.

```
count = "1"
for row in assets_tab.iter_rows(min_row=19, min_col = 3,max_col=50):
    device+count = {
        "hostName": row[7].value
    }
    device+count["hostName"]
```

But I get an error with this

```
    device+count = {
    ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to operator
```

I'm happy to keep digging on the second question, but I wanted to see if that really is the best way to go, or if there is maybe a better option.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

These two questions really should have been asked as two separate questions.

### Reading data by column header

AFAIK and from a glance at the docs there is no inbuilt way to do this, but nothing stops you doing it manually.

Say your header row is row 1.

```py
header_row = ["col1", "col2", "another col","hostName"] # get this by reading the file
```

Now you just replace your hard coded numbers with lookups in this row:

```py
hostname_col = header_row.index("hostName")
for row in rows:
    hostname = row[hostname_col]
    ...
```

### storing stuff

I think you are confused about what you want to do.  You probably just want to use a list here:

```py
data = []
for row in rows:
    val = do_stuff()
    data.append(val)
```

If you really wanted to use a dict, you could do it like this, with your semantics:

```py
data = {}
count = 1
for row in rows:
    data[count] = do_stuff(row)
    count += 1
```

But for this case this would make no sense.

There are quite a lot of other confusing things about your second question: I don't know why `count` is a *string* (since you can't then do `count += 1` to make it bigger.

If this doesn't answer your second question you are better splitting it off as a new question, and setting out *exactly* what you want to do as clearly as you can.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look over the second part of this and see if I can figure things out, if not I'll post it as a separate question, sorry for the lack of etiquette, I figured this would make it easier on people.

As for the "count" being a string, that was my mistake. As I mentioned in the beginning, I'm almost a solid novice with Python and I wasn't sure what the best way to keep a running counter was. I didn't want to spend my time working through that if it wasn't going to be the best way to store the data in the first place.